# How can i avoid from the ScrollBar in dataGridView from being moving up each update?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the constructor i set:

```
dataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
```

Then i added rows ot the dataGridView1 i call this method from a timer event and i clear the items and add again each 5 seconds. The problem is when i drag the scroll bar on the right down to see other processes when it's updating it it's moving the scrollbar back up automatic.

In windows task manager it's not doing it. I can scroll down stay down and it will keep update it.

This is the method that is called every 5 seconds from a timer tick event:

```
void PopulateApplications()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();           
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists(p.MainModule.FileName))
                    {
                        var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
                        ima = icon.ToBitmap();
                        ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
                        ima.Save(@"c:\temp\ima.jpg");
                        String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ima, p.ProcessName, status);
                        DoubleBuffered1(dataGridView1, true);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    string t = "error";
                }
            }
```

If i remove the dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); line then it will work but then it will also keep adding rows all over again each 5 seconds.

The Clearing make the scroll bar to automatic scroll up each time i deag it down.

This is an image i marked with ellipse the scroll bar i'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: You are clearing the grid each time, which forces a redraw. A redraw resets everything. You will notice in Task Manager, it UPDATES the row and/or re-orders it depending on which column you clicked. It never clears the entire grid and redraw's

Comment: First of all wrap code into `dataGridView1.BeginUpdate()`/`EndUpdate()`, otherwise updates of datagridview will occurs after each `Row.Add()`. Second, `DoubleBuffered1()` looks suspicious, are you sure want to call it after adding every item? From my experience, re-setting content (not sure if it's datagridview, more likely `ListView`) doesn't change scroll position, only selection (*viewport* still where it was, if I can say it this way), key here is to use `BeginUpdate`/`EndUpdate`. You can save selection before `Clear` and then restore it, if you care about selection.

Comment: Sinatr the dataGridView1 dosen't have any beginupdate or endupdate properties.

Comment: user303642 the reason i clear it is cause im using timer and i want to make sure that if i run a new process or stop running process it will update the entire list of processes in the dataGridView1. Your idea is to clear each clicked column but i want to update/clear for each time a new process is running or stopped.

Comment: I saw now treeview listbox listview have the beginupdate endupdate but datagridview dosent have it.

Comment: Maybe using a treeview or listview will be better way ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to scroll down on every refresh right? Try this code

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code selects the first item, so it is scrolled to the top. If you save the previous selection, you can scroll back to it. Before updating, save a reference to the row:

```
DataGridViewRow selectedRow = null;
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
   selectedRow = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
```

Then after update scroll to that row:

```
 if (selectedRow != null)
    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = selectedRow.Index;
```