# C# Winforms: Inserting an item to datagridview's top moves scroll down

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a datagridview bind to a datatable through datagridview's datasource property. Rows are added one by one and always at the datagridview's top using below line of code, for example:

```
DataRow newRow = myDataTable.NewRow();
newRow[0] = "column1 value";
newRow[1] = "column2 value";
myDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);
```

The problem is that datagridview vertical scroll moves down making not visible the last row added at the top of the datagridview so I do not want vertical scroll to move down in order to make visible last row inserted at top.

How can I do this?

**ATTEMPT 1**:

```
DataGridViewRow selectedRow = null;
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
   selectedRow = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];

DataRow newRow = myDataTable.NewRow();
newRow[0] = "column1 value";
newRow[1] = "column2 value";
myDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);

if (selectedRow != null)
   dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = selectedRow.Index;
else
   dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0;
```

extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059381/how-can-i-avoid-from-the-scrollbar-in-datagridview-from-being-moving-up-each-upd).

Seems not working. dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex always is 0 but datagridview continues scrolling down.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to scroll to the top of the DataGridView each time you add a new row. 
You can do so by setting the property [FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex(VS.90).aspx)
to the very first row which has the index 0:

```
dataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0;
```

Comment: How about the selected row(s)? Are there any?

Comment: No, never. There is no rows selected. dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

`FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` will work if you work with datagridview on direct.

For example:

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("firstColumn", "Name");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("secondColumn", "Mark");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(99);

        for (int i = 99; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            dataGridView1[0, i].Value = "column1 value " + (100 - i);
            dataGridView1[1, i].Value = "column2 value " + (100 - i);
        }

        dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]